# Thread inside module and add value into me.texbox1

Tags: vb.net

Have anyone idea why my code return "" inside my Textbox ? :-)

This i have in main Class

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
   Dim My_Thread as Threading.Thread
   My_Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Module1.MyTest)
   My_Thread.Start()
End Sub
```

And this in module1

```
Sub MyTest()
   Dim TestingValue as string = "Test"
   MainForm.Textbox1.Text = TestingValue
End sub
```

Invoke all time crash code and another try return "" inside texbox1 :-/

Comment: You can only update the UI from the UI thread.

Comment: Pass the instance of MainForm to the method. Otherwise you'll create a new instance of MainForm, so it has no handle at that point (and wouldn't do anything anyway). Then `BeginInvoke()` the instance object. You can call your method as `My_Thread.Start(Me)`. Modify the method to accept a parameter.

Comment: I try, but didnt work for me :-/ 
"System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.'"

Comment: Just wrote about that. Did you read that comment? You can run a Task instad of starting a Thread. Maybe it's easier.

Comment: i was read but I don't know how make it correctly -.- i never use beginInvoke before and please how i can create new instance of MainForm ? Very thx :-)

Comment: You **don't** have to create a new instance. Try this: `Sub MyTest(ctrl As Object) Dim tBox = DirectCast(ctrl, Control)     Dim testingValue As String = "Test" tBox.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() tBox.Text = testingValue)) End Sub`. Start the thread with `My_Thread.Start(Me.TextBox1)` (I suppose that `Me` is `MainForm`, here)

Comment: You can use `New Action()` instead of `New MethodInvoker()`.

Comment: It's working :-) Thx... its same if i use more then one textbox ? :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Since you can pass an **object** (anything, in practice) you can pass an array/List of controls. If that's what you're asking. `BeginInvoke()` each of them.

Comment: i mean if i use textbox1, textbox2, textbox3.... its better solution to create array for this ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're using this thread for or why you're using a thread in the first place. So what is *better* or *best* it's an use-case evaluation. You're the only one who can say what's best.

Comment: in this module i use some HTTP request to get data for my variables... but this code must run constantly, that's why need use thread. But i have 10-15 textboxs in this code (module) and i don't have idea what is best solution to add values...

Comment: but your code work nice for one textbox now i try use for multiple :-)

Comment: HTTP requests/responses are asynchronous by nature. You can just learn how to use the `async`/`await` patter and use the async version of the different functions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Sub Class with public declarations to any object you want on MainForm, then pass the class as a parameter to the module. This would be a cleaner approach than passing the entire Form class instance. Then using the method that Jimi has suggested you can setyou textboxs without cross thread violation.

```
    Public Class MainForm

        Public Class PassToModule
            Public TxBx1 As TextBox = MainForm.TextBox1
            Public TxBx2 As TextBox = MainForm.TextBox2
        End Class

        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim PassToModule As New PassToModule

            Dim My_Thread As Threading.Thread
            My_Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf MyTest)
            My_Thread.Start(PassToModule)

        End Sub

    End Class

    Module Module1

        Dim FromMainForm As MainForm.PassToModule

        Sub MyTest(PasToModule As MainForm.PassToModule)
            FromMainForm = PasToModule
            FromMainForm.TxBx1.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                                                 FromMainForm.TxBx1.Text = "Test"
                                                                 FromMainForm.TxBx2.Text = "Test"
                                                             End Sub))
        End Sub

    End Module
```